# ffmpeg: how to force divx5 tag?

Tags: ffmpeg

Make a divx4 is easy

```
ffmpeg -y -i original.mpg -acodec mp3 -c:v mpeg4 -vtag DIVX -b:v 1500k -b:a 128k -vf crop=544:400:1:1,scale=496:288 myfile.avi
```

Is recognized as divx4

```
mediainfo  myfile.avi|grep Codec
Codec ID                                 : DIVX
Codec ID/Info                            : Project Mayo
Codec ID/Hint                            : DivX 4
```

How to force to divx5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-vtag DX50`. See [fourcc: DIVX](https://www.fourcc.org/divx/).